# Google Calendar trigger failure

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, calendar, eventtrigger

I have developed a conferencing extension for Google Calendar. In order to listen to events, when a user installs my app for the first time, I register a trigger called "onCalendarEventClick" which creates a new event.

However, I have encountered a problem where the trigger initially works, but after a few days, it fails to trigger.

In the previous version, I would register and unregister the user trigger for each created event. This approach ensured that the trigger always triggered, but it caused another issue. The same event would trigger multiple times in an infinite loop. To address this problem, we have modified the extension installation process to register and unregister the trigger, rather than doing it for each event creation.

My current code:

```
function createTrigger() {
  try {
    console.log("createTrigger event created");
    // Get the current user's email address
    if (Session.getActiveUser() != null) {
      var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
      if (currentUser != null) {
        // Get the user's default calendar
        var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();

        // Get the existing trigger ID for the current user
        var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
        var triggerId = userProperties.getProperty(currentUser + '_calendarTrigger');
        console.log(triggerId, currentUser, "currentUser >>>>");

        // Check if a trigger already exists for the current user
        var createTrigger = true;
        if (triggerId) {
          // A trigger already exists for the current user, so remove it
          ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(function(trigger) {
            console.log(trigger.getUniqueId(), triggerId, "triggers");
            if (trigger.getUniqueId() === triggerId) {
              // ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
              createTrigger = false;
            }
          });
        }
        console.log(createTrigger, "createTrigger debugging >>>>>>>");

        if (createTrigger) {
          console.log('creating trigger again >>>');
          // Create a new trigger for calendar events for the current user
          // It triggers for all events: save, update, and delete.
          var newTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('onCalendarEventClick')
            .forUserCalendar(calendar.getId())
            .onEventUpdated()
            .create();
          // Save the new trigger ID for the current user
          userProperties.setProperty(currentUser + '_calendarTrigger', newTrigger.getUniqueId());
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message, "Something went wrong while creating triggers");
    return;
  }
}
```

#google_calendar_extension

I want to get work my trigger working and prevent multiple times triggering the single trigger

Comment: Sorry ,let me give example:
My purpose to listen event when user create ,update and delete google calendar event when user selected mine google workspace app ,its like zoom

Comment: I don't understand your last comment